# TensorProduct of square

Tags: evaluation

TensorProduct shows a behavior I don't understand when giving as an argument the square of a variable.
Example:

```
TensorProduct[a,b]
a\[TensorProduct]b
```

But for the square:

```
TensorProduct[a^2,b]
a^2*b
```

The TensorProduct gets evaluated as a standard product in the second case.
Is there a reason why Mathematica does that or is it a bug?

Comment: It's funny that even this input leads to vanishing of tensor product: `AA\[TensorProduct]BB /. AA -> AA^2`

Comment: Hm. Maybe `a^2` is assumed to be a scalar? This assumption is not too artificial since the usual definition of `Power` for arrays (aka tensors) is not covariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HenrikSchumacher's comment is spot-on. Consider:

```
TensorRank[a]
TensorRank[a^2]
```

> TensorRank[a]
>
> 0

Mathematica does some automatic simplifications of [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) objects with scalars. Another manifestation:

```
g /: TensorRank[g] = 0;

TensorProduct[a, g]
```

> a g